# Topology boundary question

Tags: general-topology

Find a nonempty bounded open set $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R^2}$ such that there is no continuous, injective map from $[0,1]$ to $\partial\Omega$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add "non-empty".

Comment: **Hint:** Can you think of a very simple open set whose boundary is not connected? The example I'm thinking of should have a familiar ring to it (heh).

Comment: Do you want there to be no continuous injective map from $[0,1]$ ***onto*** $\partial \Omega$?

Comment: Surjectivity is fine. I think it's equivalent to saying that $\partial\Omega$ does not contain a simple path

Comment: This seems like an interesting question to me but it seems like everyone is misinterpreting what it is asking.  I can't make sense of the one answer so far.  Also someone downvoted the problem and I have no idea why.

Comment: @Seth:  Because it is trivially easy to find examples.

Answer (score 0):

(Under the standard topology...)

I like the complement of the Topologist's Whirlpool (in the unit disk).  It's connected, but not path-connected...

I also like $\{(x,y)\mid 1/2 < \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}<1\}$ which unavoidably noncontinuous.  As is the (open) unit disc without $\{(x,y) \mid y^2=x^3-x\}$.

Further, $\left( (-1,1) \times (-1,1) \right) \setminus \{(x,y) \mid |x|=|y|\}$ causes all kinds of problems for injectivity.  Just ask Euler.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Method one: make the boundary of $\Omega$ have to disjoint pieces.  Then there is no continuous map to (all of) $\partial\Omega$.  Method two:  make the boundary self-crossing so that there is no Eulerian path.  Then there is no injective map to (all of) $\partial\Omega$.  It's actually rather hard to pick a bounded open *arbitrary* set that doesn't violate the desired condition (that its boundary be injectively path-connected).

Comment: The question does not assert the map is onto.  You misunderstood the question just like everyone else.

Comment: @Seth:  Then the question is trivial in the other direction.  When everyone interprets something one way except you, which is more likely:  everyone is wrong or you are?

Comment: I don't understand.  You are interpreting the question as "no continous bijective map to the boundary"?  How is that the same as "no continuous injective map to the boundary"?  If you are interpreting it as the former why not just use a ball as a counter example?

Comment: @Seth:  (1)  Because I read "Surjectivity is fine." from the OP.  (2)  That works too.  See, this is easy.

Comment: I didn't read that comment.  But that completely changes the problem and I was reading the question originally posed which does not seem trivial.