# Is there a nonempty open bounded subset of plane whose boundary contains no 1 dimensional interval?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Someone asked a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717689/topology-boundary-question) which hasn't received a correct answer because everyone seems to be misinterpreting the question.  I would like to ask the question again.

Does there exist a nonempty bounded open subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that there is no continuous injective map $[0,1]\to \partial\Omega$?

Note that I am not asking about a continuous bijection because then the problem is trivial (for example the is no continuous bijection of $[0,1]$ to the boundary of a ball).

Comment: is the answer known for the mandelbrot set?

Comment: @user126154 The mandelbrot set is closed, so technically the answer is no. But the boundary has Haussdorf dimension $2$, so it might work.

Comment: ok, take the interior, or the complement (which is open and "bounded" if you exchange $0$ and $\infty$)

Comment: may be there is some "easy" example in the class of limit set of Klenian groups. (again, "bundedness" is equivalent to ask that $\Omega$ is not dense, as we can always put a point in the interior of the complement and put it to $\infty$)

Comment: what about asking on MathOverflow?

Comment: I could try that if nobody is able to solve the problem in a day or two.  I'm wondering if there is any classification of which closed sets are boundaries of open sets.  Can we say anything about local path connectedness?  There are definitely boundaries which are not locally path connected at certain points.  But we would need one that is not locally path connected at any point.

Comment: I made some search on MO, and there is almost an answer. Since here the discussion seems dead, I decided then to ask in MO for a general answer.  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/161247/is-the-complement-of-a-closed-totally-path-disconnected-set-of-the-sphere-conne

Comment: Wow! in MO there is already the answer, vith an explicit example!!!

Comment: Thanks for doing that!  Can you explain why in this case asking for the boundary of an open non dense set satisfying these conditions is the same as asking for a bounded open set satisfying these conditions?  Your previous explanation was over my head.  Also if you understand the example they gave could you give an intuitive idea of what is going on?  I have to say that right now I don't understand the answer at all.

Comment: boundendens is equivalent to nondense because a bounded set is clearly non-dense. On the other hand, if $X$ is non-dense, let $y\notin X$. Then yuo can exchange the infinity and $x$ first by commpattify the plane to a sphere by adding $\infty$, then by using a stereographic projection with pole $x$.

Comment: That is to say, there is an homeo of $\mathbb R^2\setminus x$ which "exchange" $x$ and $\infty$. Under suc omeomorphism $X$ becomes bounded and the ohter properties are preserved.

Comment: I see, that makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @Seth as for the example, I have no particuarly good intuitions. The wiki pages about pseudo-arc contains nice pictures and some explanation

Comment: @Seth may be this helps: you can imagine to have a horizontal stick --- (a thin rectancle) Then you put another thinner rectangle  inside the first, as a Z-shape inside  --- (think the "Z" to be very long in horizontal an very thin in vertical). Then you do that recursively. The intersection of all of such Z's is a pseudo arc. Generalize this construction to a circular situation to obtain a psudo-circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As answered by Eric Wofsey on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/161247), such an open set is given by the bounded component of the complement of *pseudo-circle*. Pseudo-circle, a close relative of [pseudo-arc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc), was introduced by R.H. Bing in [Concerning hereditarily indecomposable continua](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102613150) (Pacific J. Math. Volume 1, Number 1 (1951), 43-51.). Here is a description: begin with a circular chain of disks such as the one below, then create another such chain inside, making it *crooked*, i.e., with a lot of back-and-forth movement (precise definition in Bing's paper). On the picture, the smaller chain is represented by a  polygonal curve; you should imagine covering this curve with small circles. The process continues indefinitely, and the intersection of all these chains is a pseudo-circle.

[image: pseudocircle]

The illustration is from the dissertation [Factorwise Rigidity Involving Hereditarily Indecomposable Spaces](http://books.google.com/books?id=9edZH8ExRRoC) by Kevin B. Gammon.