# Boundary of an open bounded connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ must contain the image of a path?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, connectedness, geometric-topology, plane-curves

How does one prove that the boundary of a bounded open connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ must contain the image of a path?

**I require a non-constant path. But it doesn't have to be injective.**

This thought occurred to me just now. I've looked for an answer on Google and found none.

$\\$

Would I be right in thinking that the proof might involve partitioning the plane into small squares of side length $\dfrac{1}{2^n}$, then filling in every square that overlaps with that open set, then tracing the "outer edge" of this approximation of the open set (easier to define on a shape made up of squares, I suppose), then proving that this passes to a limit, then proving that this limit is on the boundary of the open set?

I don't mind looking up other results, if the result that I want would follow from them. It's been a while since I last read a proof of the Jordan Curve Theorem. I'm asking my question here, in case there is a simple answer I've missed.

Cheers!

Comment: This question seems relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720254/is-there-a-nonempty-open-bounded-subset-of-plane-whose-boundary-contains-no-1-di

Comment: @PhoemueX thanks! but I don't actually require the path to be injective, just non-constant

Comment: The answer of Eric Wofsey (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/161247/must-a-closed-totally-path-disconnected-subset-of-the-sphere-have-connected-comp) says that the boundary is totally path-disconnected, so you also can't get a non-constant path.

Comment: @PhoemueX I see now, thanks a lot!